# Disqualification display record if exist in column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two columns in the table. Color and shape. And I would like to have only those colors that do not take a square shape.

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color
FROM t1
WHERE shape NOT IN ('square');
```

will cause that in the result I will have a yellow color, but without this line with a square shape. And I would like the existence of this shape to automatically exclude yellow.

```
Color Shape

yellow round
yellow square
yellow oval
white round
white oval
```

Comment: Could you show your expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want color which has `square` shape then you can use `not exists` instead :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.color = t.color and t1.shape = 'square');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquery here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color
FROM t1
WHERE color NOT IN (select color from t1 where shape='square');
```

**Explanation**
The subquery will return your colors with shape as square and then with **NOT IN** clause you can filter out such colors from your output

Answer (score 0):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT color
FROM t1
GROUP BY color
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN shape = 'square' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of rows that have `square`.  The `= 0` says that none exist.  Under many circumstances, this can be faster than `SELECT DISTINCT` with a `WHERE` filter.  The work the database does is similar for `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.